# Fixing website for IE etc

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, css, cross-browser

I developed a [website](http://backwardsbearandbabycurl.com/).The site works fine on Chrome `19.0.1084.46 m` but on all the other browsers(Except Mozilla), the sidebar moves below the container. Its one of my first web designs so I don't have an idea about fixes for browsers. Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the alignment properly remove the `margin-left` property that you have added in container div from `%` to `px`, as `%` will vary from screen to screen.

Here is a site that explains about the layouts: [Check it out](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/)

hope it helps :)